# JQUERY - How to write a jquery function to populate textarea field w/addresses based on dropdown option selected

Tags: jquery, html

What is the most best way to do this via jquery?

I have a dropbox [Center Title]that has a location name/title. I need to associate the address to the name and then upon change of the dropbox, I need the address to populate in two textarea boxes

There are a bunch of centers and their corresponding addresses, so I think I want to put this in an external js file.

Here is my html, I just can't get the jquery clear in my head.

```
<fieldset name="Group1">
                <legend>Group box</legend>
                Center Title:<select name="ctrTitles" id="ctrTitles">
                <option value="Corp 1">Corp 1</option>
                <option value="Shamrock Gold">Shamrock Gold</option>
                <option value="Hensin Way">Hensin Way</option>
            </select><br /><br />
            Address 1: <textarea name="TextArea1" id="TextArea1" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea><br /><br />
            Address 2: <textarea name="TextArea2" id="TextArea2"cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
            </fieldset>
```

​view my jsFiddle here: `http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/WcXpk/`

Comment: do you mean this functionality? http://jsfiddle.net/WcXpk/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $('#ctrTitles').change(function() {
       var centreName = $(this).val();

    var address = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < centerLocations.length; ++i) {
    if (centerLocations[i].value == centreName) {
    address = centerLocations[i].address;
break;
    }

    }

       $("#TextArea1, #TextArea2").val(address);    
    });​
```

Comment: Beyond Excellent - if you knew how much code I originally had :(  Thank you so MUCH!!!

Answer (score 3):

something like this?

```
$('#ctrTitles').change(function() {
   address = $(this).val();
   $("#TextArea1, #TextArea2").val(address);    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WcXpk/3/

Comment: This updates the two address fields to the name of the center, rather than its address from the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select#ctrTitles').change(function() {
    var index = $(':selected', this).index();
    $("#TextArea1, #TextArea2").val(centerLocations[index]['address']); // if your address array sync with `<select><option>` order
});
```

Here is complete code:

```
var centerLocations = new Array(
    {value : 'Corp 1', address : 'Address 1'},
    {value : 'Shamrock Gold', address : 'Shamrock Gold Address 2'},
    {value : 'Hensin Way', address : 'Hensin Way Address 3'}
);

function findAddress(value) {
    var address = '';
    $.each(centerLocations, function() {
        if(new RegExp(this.value, 'ig').test(value)) {
            address = this.address;
        }
    });
    return address;
}
$('select#ctrTitles').change(function() {
    var index = $(':selected', this).index(),
        val = $(this).val();
    $("#TextArea1, #TextArea2").val(findAddress(val));
});
```

Comment: this is the same as what i did but simpler

Answer (score 0):

i guess you want the value in the adress1 textarea
http://jsfiddle.net/WcXpk/4/

Comment: Actually the "address" is what will go into the "address 1" and the "address 2' textarea boxes once the "value" matches what was selected from the dropdown.

Comment: why would you need the same adress in both textareas?

Comment: Client has two boxes appear in different areas on the actual web form.